# Disable Sound Output Device, MacOS Catalina 10.15.4

Tags: macos, audio

I like to deactivate some of my audio devices but I can't even remove them easily:

As you can see in [3] - the remove button ('-') is inactive (this goes for all devices) - my guess is, that I could do that somehow as sudo?

Nevertheless.. basically i'd like to achieve to >hide< the devices in 1 (resp. seen in [2] (audio MIDI setup app) but the secondary CalDigit is an optical audio plug, therefore it won't show up and bother me until plugged in which means it can be left untouched).

Is there a way? (I'd prefer disable/hide over remove for I'm not sure I'll be able to reattach it in case of need)

[image]

Comment: What are BenQ  PD1300U 1 and PD1300U 2? Are they devices?

Comment: If you select **one** device is the gear icon/menu active and can you *disable* it that way rather than removing it?

Comment: BenQ id a display maker. Presumably these are on HDMI & report having an audio path. You cannot remove hardware items from that list in Audio Midi, so you'll probably have to look for some way the manufacturer may allow the 'speakers' to be disabled.

Comment: @Tetsujin thx for that. I’m not very familiar with the depths of MacOS, yet. However hence it’s unix heritage, i‘ll try to script sth. to modify the task bar (or what is called in this world^^) - u wouldn’t know if there‘re any build up restrictions by Apple which would prevent me from that?@jmh - tetsujin is right, it indicated the audio channels of the speakers in the BenQ monitors. Furthermore CalDigit represents the busses of a hub and below the build-in devices there is an additional one connected via AirPlay2.

Comment: @SteveChambers as you can determine by the blue highlighting, there is already only **one** selected device ;) - but it‘s the same for all of them (separately checked)